# Find center, radius and a tangent to $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+3=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

> For the circle  $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+3=0$ find
>   a) The center and radius
>   b) The equation of the tangent line at the point $(-2,5)$

Now, I solved a) and got the equation
$$(x+3)^2+(y-2)^2=10$$ with center $=(-3,2)$ and radius $=\sqrt{10}$
Now, I've never learned about the tangent of a circle, but I think that it's a line that touches the outer end of a circle. But I'm not 100% on that. So if anyone can help me out with this, that would be very beneficial. And please **do not** solve this for me.

Comment: In $(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=\sqrt10$,shouldn´t that be:
 $(x-3)^2+(y-2)^2=10$?
Because is in this form:$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=R^2$.If you say that the radius is $\sqrt 10$,then in the formula you have only $10$.

Comment: Yes, it should be $${\left( {x + 3} \right)^2} + {\left( {y - 2} \right)^2} = 10$$

Comment: @AndréNicolas For sure!(forgot the minus signal...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line tangent to the circle at $(-2,5)$ is the straight line through $(-2,5)$ that is perpendicular to the radius of the circle that runs from the centre of the circle at $(-3,2)$ to the point $(-2,5)$. Find the slope of that radius, use that to get the slope of the tangent line, and you’re on your way.

**Edit**: I just corrected the $x$-coordinate of the centre. Yours has the wrong sign: $x+3=x-(-3)$, so the correct $x$-coordinate is $-3$.

Comment: So. Find the slope from the radius to $(-2,5)$ and then find the perpendicular slope?

Comment: @Austin: Yes, and then use the point-slope form to find the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: The slope from the center point to $(-2,5)$ is $\dfrac{3}{1}$. Which would mean the perpendicular slope is $-\dfrac{1}{3}$. So, would that make $y=-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{13}{3}$?

Comment: @Austin: The straight line with slope $m$ passing through the point $(a,b)$ has the equation $y-b=m(x-a)$; this is called the *point-slope* form of the equation of the straight line. Once you have this, you can easily transform it to the slope-intercept form (your $y=mx+b$).

Comment: @AustinBroussard Now you have the slope and a point on the line. As Brian stated earlier, use the **point-slope** form of the equation of a line to finish the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let us complete the square. We get $x^2+6*x+9+y^2-4*y+4-9-4+3=0$ or $(x+3)^2+(y-2)^2=10$. Your circle is with center $O(-3,2)$ and radius $r=\sqrt{10}$

For the second question, let us calculate slope, which would  be $\text{rise}/\text{run}$ or in our case center is $(-3,2)$  so slope=$(5-2)/(-2+3)=3$  slope of  tangent line would be $-1/3$ put this conditions into form of tangent line $y=mx+b$ we get $5=-1/3\cdot(-2)+b$  or $b=5-2/3=13/3$

We get equation of tangent line
$y=-1/3\cdot x+13/3$

Answer (score 2):

Since the question has already been settled nicely, let me demonstrate an unconventional way to find the tangent of a circle through a given point on the circle.

There are three things that allow us to do what we will be doing in the sequel:

1. Any point can be thought of as a "point-circle"; that is, **a circle of radius $\textbf 0$**.
2. One can always produce the equation for [the radical line](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadicalLine.html) of two circles.
3. The radical line of two tangent circles is their common tangent line.

Here, now, is the procedure. We are given the point $(-2,5)$ on the circle $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+3=0$. Constructing the equation of a point-circle is a snap (note that as always, we negate the coordinates of the center when inserting them into the equation of a circle):

$$(x+2)^2+(y-5)^2=0$$

which in expanded form, looks like

$$x^2+y^2+4x-10y+29=0$$

From the equivalence of the tangent line and the radical line in this case that I mentioned earlier, all we have to do to find the tangent line to your circle is to find the radical line of the given circle and the point-circle. (Certainly, a point circle lying on another circle is necessarily tangent to it.) The equation of the radical line is easily produced by just subtracting the two given equations; thus,

$$(x^2+y^2+6x-4y+3)-(x^2+y^2+4x-10y+29)=0$$

or, after simplification and solving for $y$,

$$y=\frac{13-x}{3}$$

is the sought radical line, which is also the tangent line of the circle $x^2+y^2+6x-4y+3=0$ through $(-2,5)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, where did the square root come from? The sign of $3$ is wrong.

You are right that the tangent line is one that touches the circle in one point.  The slope of the tangent to a curve is given by the derivative at that point.  So rearrange your equation to $y= $ some function of $x$, take $\frac {dy}{dx}$, and evaluate it at $(-2,5)$.  When you rearrange the equation you will have a square root and need to think about the sign.

Comment: I never took pre-calculus. I'm skipping from trigonometry to calculus. I know nothing about derivatives. Sorry.

Comment: @AustinBroussard try to take a look at this [one](http://http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjmHBeUticA)

Comment: The question is clearly tagged as "algebra-precalculus", so a non-calculus solution should be suggested.